Connect to Intel DevCloud from Jetbrains Gateway
The Intel DevCloud for oneAPI connection guide has information for: OpenSSH or Cygwin on Windows, Linux or MacOS, and Visual Studio Code. I would like to connect to it from Jetbrains Gateway.
It is clear that I'll need to use SSH. However, there does not seem to be enough settings in the application for configuring it correctly. How do I do it?


Configure your SSH client using the VSCode instructions, which are provided
On the Connect to SSH window in Gateway, open the list of SSH hosts, and add a new one
Host can be devcloud
Port is 22
Username should be the value of the User property of the SSH config from step one
Authentication type should be OpenSSH config and authentication agent
Strict host key checking should be No
Click ok, select the host, and connect.

You might also want to update your ~/.bashrc file to request a job on startup. GPU example:
if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]] ; then
        qsub -I -l nodes=1:gpu:ppn=2 -d .
fi

